# Use ng-show and etc. in directive "A"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I saw related asks, but dont understand anyway.

If I have directive: http://pastebin.com/QtAzGv62
And I need to add "ng-show" (or any other standart angular directive) functional to this directive (for related DOM element, that is ), that must depends on AuthService option (named "logged").

How?! :)

Comment: Please have a look on a source code of ng-show directive: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L3. There are in fact 2 lines of code... I'm sure you can do the same thing in your directive, no need to reuse that one :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not binding to a particular 'element' you just need to make the methods available to your directive scope so change

```
elem.bind('click', function() {
    AuthService.tryLogin();
});
```

to

```
scope.loggedIn = false;
scope.tryLogin = function(){
    AuthService.tryLogin();  
    scope.loggedIn = true;
}
```

Then you can do in your directive html

```
<div ng-show="loggedIn">You dun logged in man!</div>
```